# PHP Xpath: Matching the root node in an HTML snippet

Tags: php, xpath

```
$document = new \DOMDocument();
\libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$document->loadHTML('<a/>');
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($document);
echo $xpath->query('/a')->length."\n";
echo $xpath->query('a')->length."\n";
```

This code produces two zeroes instead of the expected two ones. Why, and what query or other changes (other than changing the query to `//a`) will produce the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

When / is used at the beginning of a path:

/a

... it will define an absolute path to node "a" relative to the root. As such, in this case, it will only find "a" nodes at the root of the XML tree.

When // is used at the beginning of a path:

//a

... it will define a path to node "a" anywhere within the XML document. As such, in this case, it will find "a" nodes located at any depth within the XML tree.

Answer (score 1):

In a standard HTML document the root node is `<html>`, then you have your `<head>`, `<body>`, and then whatever else. I'll assume your `<a>` is in a `<div>` in the `<body>`

A full Xpath identifier to the  would be as follows:

```xml
/html/body/div/a
```

This would give you a single result, and what you are looking for. However, this is a basic HTML page, and probably unrealistically simple.

Xpath gives you the ability to *skip* sections of the Xpath by using the `//` (double slash).

```xml
/html//a -> any <a> tag in the <html>
//div/a -> any <a> tag that is directly in a <div> that exists anywhere
//a -> any <a> tag anywhere that exists anywhere
```

So by searching for `/a`, you are searching for an `<a>` tag at the beginning of your HTML document, which is not really ever the case - hence, no results.

Comment: The node in question is an HTML snippet, not a full HTML document. Your assumption is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$document->loadHTML()` to `$document->loadXML()`.